# How many pipeline stages does the Intel Core i7 have?

Tags: x86, pipeline

How many instructions it can handle at a time ?

Comment: What kind of instructions? Integer? x87 Floating point? SIMD Floating point?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to handle an instruction? It can only perform as many operations as there are CPU cores. Anything else optimizes the order of execution?

Comment: The title and the question body are two different things.  Also, `i7` doesn't differentiate between Nehalem, Sandybridge, or later CPUs.  The pipeline width is 4 fused-domain uops, and [the ROB size is 168 entries (SnB) or 128 entries (Nehalem).](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/5/).  Even more instructions than that can be "in the pipeline" if you include decoded insns that haven't issued into the out-of-order core yet.  See more links to info in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Answer (score 8):

http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/cpus/2008/11/03/intel-core-i7-nehalem-architecture-dive/5

> Penryn's pipeline was a very nippy 14 stages, while in comparison
>   Nehalem extends this quite considerably to 20-to-24 stages.

Answer (score 8):

[Agner Fog's documentation](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) is a very good resource to understand what's going on.  Reading it should help you understand.  There's a limit to the number of instructions that are outstanding (the size of the retirement buffer), but there are many other limits that you'll likely hit before reaching that bottleneck, such as instruction decoder limitations, execution unit contention, ALU/divider pressure.  Take a look, it's fascinating stuff!